# Use RadListView with nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I would liek to know how can I use RadListView with nativescript-vue.

Currently I load the RadListView :

```
// Rad List View
import RadListView from 'nativescript-ui-listview/vue';
Vue.use(RadListView);
```

Use in component :

```
<template>
  <Page>
    <ActionBar>
      <Label text="Home"/>
    </ActionBar>

    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
      <RadListView ref="listView" for="post in getFeed" height="50%">
        <v-template>
          <Label :text="post.id" />
        </v-template>
      </RadListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </Page>
</template>
```

But I have this error **Uncaught ReferenceError: TKListViewDelegate is not defined** :

```
(CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Uncaught ReferenceError: TKListViewDelegate is not defined
at (file: app/webpack:/@nativescript/template-blank-vue/node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.ios.js:516:0) at ./node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.ios.js(file: app/webpack:/@nativescript/template-blank-vue/node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/ui-listview.ios.js:518:1)
```

My pakages.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/core": "^8.0.5",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.1",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-socketio": "^4.0.1",
    "@triniwiz/nativescript-toasty": "^4.1.3",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.9.0",
    "nativescript-vue-devtools": "^1.5.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "beta",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^9.1.0",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.9.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.5.27",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the RadListView NPM package.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this plugin: https://github.com/nativescript-community/ui-collectionview.
It performs better and is constantly being updated